# Microsoft Graph SDK ErrorInvalidRecipients when sending draft email for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to send an email for a user using Microsoft Graph SDK 5.13.0. I am receiving "ErrorInvalidRecipients" - "At least one recipient is not valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients".

Here's my code:

```
var graphMessage = new Message
{
  Subject = "Test",
  Body = new ItemBody
  {
    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    Content = "Test"
  },
  ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
  {
    new Recipient
    {
      EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
      {
        Address = "***@***.com"
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create draft to be able to add large attachments
var draftMessage = await client.Users["no-reply@***.com"].Messages.PostAsync(graphMessage);

// Attachments would be added to draftMessage

var body = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
  Message = draftMessage
};

// Produces "ErrorInvalidRecipients" error code
await client.Users["no-reply@***.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find anything in the documentation that mentions this yet but it turns out the error was a result of using:

```
await client.Users["no-reply@***.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(body);
```

The correct way is to use:

```
await client.Users["no-reply@***.com"].Messages[body.Message.Id].Send.PostAsync();
```

Since I was trying to send a draft message, `SendMail` was not working correctly (or wasn't designed for drafts). `SendMail` works correctly if I don't create drafts.